# How do you best use .default files to reset service settings in OS X Server?

Tags: configuration, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

Can someone explain the logic behind .default and .orig files in OS X Server? The configuration files (eg: .conf, .cf files) for most services (postfix, dovecot, etc etc) have these files to help you nuke them when things go wrong.

I suppose my question is really an umbrella for two smaller questions:

a) What's the difference between .default and .orig files?

b) Are you supposed to cp the .default (or .orig) file to make it active, or is it enough to delete the wonky configuration file (I've experimented and this does seem to trigger the OS to copy the default, but I'm not sure if it's the ideal way to do things)

Answer (score 2):

Apple Support Docs always suggest copying the ".default" file, so this is definitly the one to go [to reset a service].

As for the difference between the default and orig I can only assume:
Apple does use OpenSource but mostly with a custom implementation (different paths and so on) so the ".original" could be the original OpenSource config while the ".default" could be the "Apple default"